# Answering Duplicate Questions with Answers from original post

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

When viewing question #1 that is most likely a duplicate of question #2, what's the appropriate way to answer question #1 with an answer from question #2?

Now, I feel it would be safe to say that giving credit to the original answer from #1 is a good start, but even though we're dealing with "imaginary" points on SE, part of me feels guilty for gaining any reputation through simply echoing another user's answer.

Should I even bother answering the question, or simply leave a comment that references the original question?

Comment: Duplicate questions should be closed as duplicates. The process allows you to select the older duplicate. When you do this, a link will be added to question #1 pointing to question #2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ideal approach is to [close the question as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).

However, this might not be possible due to insufficient reputation, in which case you should flag the question as a duplicate. That will post an automatic comment on your behalf linking to the other question, *and* put the question into the Duplicate review queue for voting by users with enough rep to close it.

Comment: I didn't even think of the insufficient rep. aspect, that's good point. Thanks!

Comment: Flags can be used in the case of insufficient rep. This will put the question in the Duplicate review queue for users that have enough rep.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Good to know!